# How to restore AWS Aurora Snapshot to a t3.micro instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When restoring an Aurora snapshot from the UI, there's this option available:

[image]

However, I can't find anything in the AWS RDS SDK that supports configuring this option when restoring the snapshot. There's nothing here that talks about it either: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot.html

Am I supposed to restore the db cluster from snapshot and *then* modify the configuration of the restored cluster?

Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would specify: `--db-cluster-instance-class db.t3`

In boto3 (Python), the parameter is called `DBClusterInstanceClass`.

For a list of available values, see: [Aurora DB instance classes - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html)